# Passing multiple values to credit card debit

Tags: php, balanced-payments

I am trying to pass three values to debit transaction in balanced payments using PHP.

I am able to create a transaction successfully when I do this:

```
$transaction=$customer->debit($total*100);
```

as opposed to defining $transaction as an array.  When I create the array below I get an error.  I have reviewed the API docs but there is no example with multiple values being passed in PHP.

```
function new_transaction($cc_token=NULL, $total=NULL, $order_id=NULL){ 

    $customer = \Balanced\Customer::get('/v1/customers/CU7MPeEt3DhflopxaeFG');
    $transaction=$customer->debit(array(
        "amount"        => $total*100,
        "source_uri"    => $cc_token,
        "appears_on_statement_as" => 'Order #'.$order_id,
    ));     

    return $transaction->uri;

}
```

Sorry I didn't think to post the error since it is opaque - here it is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Balanced\Errors\Error' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merchantfuse/application/libraries/balanced/balanced/src/Balanced/Errors.php:35
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merchantfuse/application/libraries/balanced/balanced/src/Balanced/Resource.php(24):
>   Balanced\Errors\Error::createFromResponse(Object(Httpful\Response)) #1
>   [internal function]:
>   Balanced\Resource::convertError(Object(Httpful\Response)) #2
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merchantfuse/application/libraries/balanced/restful/src/RESTful/Client.php(69):
>   call_user_func('Balanced\Resour...', Object(Httpful\Response)) #3
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merchantfuse/application/libraries/balanced/restful/src/RESTful/Client.php(34):
>   RESTful\Client->_op(Object(Httpful\Request)) #4
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merchantfuse/application/libraries/balanced/restful/src/RESTful/Collection.php(35):
>   RESTful\Client->post('/v1/customers/C...', Array) #5
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merchantfuse/application/libraries/balanced/balanced/src/Balanced/Customer.php
>   in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/merchantfuse/application/libraries/balanced/balanced/src/Balanced/Errors.php
>   on line 35

Comment: *"I get an error"*, Really?

Comment: Just posted the error, it's saying that there is an error on line 35 in their API library, not my code.  There is an error somewhere in the communication between our site and balanced.  Is there somewhere else where an error might be listed?

Comment: as the eoor is not in your code, you need to contact the API support

Comment: understood, the question is tagged as "Balanced_Payments" they have an active group on Stack Overflow which is why I posted it here. Should I remove the PHP tag?

Comment: PHP tag is fine, because it is php specific---Catch the exception... then display the message from the exception

Comment: My guess is that your $cc_token is incorrect.. can you var_dump the function parameters

Comment: This is the cc_token variable: /v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP7zdo0P3hVyCJv5jGH4OVPo/cards/CC1KxhXOuHYrwGR8opxLuKjQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Balanced Support I figured this out

```
function new_transaction($cc_token=NULL, $total=NULL, $order_id=NULL){  
        $customer = \Balanced\Customer::get('/v1/customers/CU7guBPfer2uEkOEopU0KgXl');
        $transaction=$customer->debit($total*100, 'Statement Info', null, 'Description, $cc_token, null);       

        return $transaction->uri;
    }
```

works...check out the function in the balanced code: 
https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Customer.php#L141